# Chokidar path resolver

Tags: chokidar

In the project I'm working on, the file structure is as following:

```
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── ...
├── scripts
│   └── start.js
├── src
│   ├── server
```

The `start.js` script uses the `chokidar` module like so:

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch('src/server')

watcher.on('ready', () => {
  watcher.on('all', () => {
    Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(id => {
        if (/[\/\\](server)[\/\\]/.test(id)) delete require.cache[id]
    })
  })
})
```

My problem is, I don't understand this path works `src/server`. I tried `../src/server` and `path.resolve('../src/server')` but none of them worked.  What am I missing?